# Basic reverse with namespaced URLs for versioned APIs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use django-rest-framework with NamespaceVersioning. My main urls.py looks like this:

```
...
url(r'^api/v1/', include('my_api.api_urls', app_name="api", namespace='v1')),
...
```

And in my_api.api_urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^some-endpoint/$', api_views.MyView.as_view(), name='some'),
]
```

Somehow I fail to be able to reverse these URLs. Why can't I just do this? I get a `NoReverseMatch` exception.

```
reverse('some')
```

I can't wrap my head around django's namespacing, but shouldn't it just use the last defined route? If I remove the namespace argument from the main url, everything works fine.

**edit**

Also not working:

```
reverse('v1:some')
```

I might also add, that, in my main urls file, I'm including multiple urls files to the api/v1/ prefix:

```
...
url(r'^api/v1/', include('my_api.api_urls', app_name="api", namespace='v1')),
url(r'^api/v1/', include('my_other_api.api_urls', app_name="api", namespace='v1')),
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When reversing url names in django, you have to reverse with `namespace:url-name` pattern.

Your reverse call should look like this:

```
reverse('v1:some')
```

See: [How to use `reverse()` in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)

**Update**: You are using same namespace on multiple url entries. Keep url namespaces unique.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#reversing-urls-for-versioned-apis ?? make sure you use `from rest_framework.reverse import reverse`'s reverse function

Comment: No luck, sorry. I guess it's got to be a problem with my config then. Could it be related with using the same namespace on multiple includes with the same prefix? When I change that particular api's namespace to something else, (e.g. 'v2') and use reverse('v2:some') it works.

Comment: Yes, most probably. Multiple urls with same namespace can cause problems. Trying changing the the namespace

Comment: Ah, then that must be the problem. So, as a rule of thumb, only use namespace once and include the sub-urls from there?

Comment: Did that fix your problem? Should I update the answer?

Comment: Yes, it fixed the problem, thanks a lot. I am now namespace/including only once.

Comment: @Nuschk how do you include multiples urls in different apps under one namespace? like `url(r'^api/v1/', include(('myapi.urls', 'myotherapi.urls',), namespace='v1'))`? Can you write on the response the working code?

Comment: @Ruben: Oh, I haven't been tinkering with this for a long time, so I'm not entirely fresh on the topic. I'm using one main urls file per API version and include everything from there. Like this: `url(r'^api/v1/', include('main.api_urls_v1', namespace='v1'))`. And, in api_urls_v1: `url_patterns = [url(r'app1/', include('app1.api.api_urls')), url(r'app2/', include('app2.api.api_urls_v1'))]`. The upside of this approach is, you can wire up the versions independently for each app. The downside is, it's a bit verbose.

Comment: @Nuschk OK, so not exactly my case, I don't have different paths for each app. Thank you anyway.